# How to turn off Reload alerts?

Tags: notepad++

In NotePad++, I generally run with a few files open. These are log files that are continually updating. I get annoyed when NotePad++ resumes focus and I get a stack of `Reload` popups informing me that some of my open files have been updated 'by another program,' and would I like to reload them.

I would like to turn this alert off and manually reload the files when it is convenient. I've looked but I cant seem to see the option. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: A new update was released yesterday that allows you to configure the ability to only check for updates in you have the tab active! No more annoying automatically switching away! https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v7.6.5.html

Answer (score 177, accepted):

If you want to reload manually, go to *Settings* \ *Preferences*, then the *MISC* tab and change *Enable* to *Disable* under **File Status Auto-detection**.  If instead you want it to update automatically without the prompt, then leave it on *Enable* and check *Update silently*.

Comment: I like the notification, but I would like to get it only when I switch to an affected tab/file. The annoying part is to get notifications about the files I am not currently looking at.

Comment: Yes, this is a poor feature. In this day and age popups are a universal source of frustration, you don't expect it from a dev tool.

Comment: Also, when it asks it, it automatically switch to the updated file, loosing current focus. And I had to open the file again, because I can't easily navigate it from all the open tabs.

Comment: This is still a frustration, even today!

Comment: Btw, there seem to be a relevant bug report on this issue: https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/1087

Comment: This question was answered in 2009 and I am surprised that the same annoying 'feature' is still there in 2016.

Comment: In the GitHub bug report listed above, someone helpfully added a new feature to fix this. It installs downloading a foreign binary or building yourself, but is worth it.

Comment: now there is an option in the same menu to get a silent update and another one to go to the last line after the update. So this is good for log files and even to prevent inadvertent rollback of file updated somewhere else !

Comment: finally desactivated !!!

Comment: I don't like the silent update and I really don't like the way notifications have been implemented.  What I don't get is that when you look through the Notepad ++ forums people have been complaining about this for 10 years and yet version after version is released ignoring the complaints and the requests to display notifications only when the tab is selected.

Comment: A new update was released yesterday that allows you to configure the ability to only check for updates in you have the tab active! No more annoying automatically switching away! https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v7.6.5.html

Comment: @JonM link 404s

Comment: @kkarakk huh weird, they've removed the page but the change notes still mention it in v7.6.6 https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v7.6.6.html

Comment: litterally the worst feature ever. the popups doesnt make sense when you're not even in/editing the file

Answer (score 4):

Like dlux said:
Settings \ Preferences, then the MISC tab and uncheck Enable under "File Status Auto-detection".

But I'd like to add something. There is a very nice plugin called 'Document Manager'. Please download the 'Document Manager' plugin from the Plugin Manager (Plugins->Plugin Manager->Show Plugins), you can then select individual documents you'd like to be silently updated regularly by enabling it for them using the little eye icon in the menu bar.  Seems a little buggy and sometimes doesn't update when it should, but generally does a nice job of it.  And again, you still have to disable File Status Auto-detection or you'll still be getting alerts as well.