# shortcut to manually Reload file from Disk

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++

Now that [I can turn off the annoying Reload popups](https://superuser.com/questions/34551/notepad-how-to-turn-off-reload-alerts), I would like a quick way to manually reload the file I am working on in NotePad++ via the keyboard.  Looking at the File menu, `Reload from Disk` does not have a shortcut.  Is there a hidden shortcut that you know of or someway to map one built-in?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

You can use the *Shortcut Mapper* under the *Settings* menu to assign a shortcut for this.

Answer (score 62):

1. Go to Settings>Shortcut mapper.
2. Select the first tab (main menu).
3. Find the "reload from disk" option.
4. Put an unused shortcut.

Comment: I thought it was a good question. Questions with simple answers are not necessarily stupid.

Comment: I used the key `F5`, as it's also the refresh key in most browsers.  Thanks, Konerak!

Answer (score 47):

While above answers are not wrong, It is already built-in : <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> then <kbd>L</kbd>

Or "File >> Reload from Disk".

Comment: I accept, but this is pretty much any windows user can do.. but setting a dedicated shortcut is advantageous as we don't need to wait for menu to popup after ALT+F..

Comment: I didn't know you could do this - and I've been on Windows for 10+ years +1

Comment: Everyone loves to come up with Complex answers to simple problems, but nobody goes for the simple answers to simple problems